# More efficient than nested loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I am trying to break my habit of `for` loops by using `apply` but I've gotten stumped on this one.  I have a for loop that collapses every two rows into one row for an object, `obj.tmp`(366 by 34343), but it is slow.

Here's a much shortened example:

```
df <- data.frame(X1 = letters[1:10], X2 = letters[11:20], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Thus:

```
> df
X1 X2
a  k
b  l
c  m
d  n
e  o
f  p
g  q
h  r
i  s
j  t

for(i in 1:(nrow(df)/2)){
  df2[i,] <- apply( df[(i*2-1):(i*2),], 2, paste, collapse = "")
}
```

Output:

```
> df2 
X1  X2
ab  kl
cd  mn
ef  op
gh  qr
ij  st
```

Suggestions on a better method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample data, here is one possibility:

```
# Sample data
df <- data.frame(X1 = letters[1:10], X2 = letters[11:20], stringsAsFactors = FALSE);

do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, gl(nrow(df) / 2, 2, nrow(df))), function(x) sapply(x, paste0, collapse = "")))
#  X1   X2
#1 "ab" "kl"
#2 "cd" "mn"
#3 "ef" "op"
#4 "gh" "qr"
#5 "ij" "st"
```

Explanation: Split `df` every two rows and store in `list`, `paste` entries by column, and `rbind` into final object.

---

If you want to avoid `rbind`ing the `list` element, you can also do:

```
t(sapply(split(df, gl(nrow(df) / 2, 2, nrow(df))), function(x) sapply(x, paste0, collapse = "")));
#  X1   X2
#1 "ab" "kl"
#2 "cd" "mn"
#3 "ef" "op"
#4 "gh" "qr"
#5 "ij" "st"
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I modify that to iterate over every column?

Comment: @Mgdesaix Please take a look at my updated solution.

Comment: Thank you for both options, that really helps

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `aggregate` function:

```
df1=cbind(df,id=rep(1:(nrow(df)/2)# Create a new df with an id that shows the rows to be combined
aggregate(.~id,df1,each=2)),paste0,collapse="")[-1]#Combine the rows

  X1 X2
1 ab kl
2 cd mn
3 ef op
4 gh qr
5 ij st
```

You can do all this in one line:

```
  aggregate(.~id,cbind(df,id=rep(1:(nrow(df)/2),each=2)),paste0,collapse="")[-1]
```

You can also try:

```
matrix(do.call(paste0,data.frame(matrix(unlist(df),,2,T))),,2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "ab" "kl"
[2,] "cd" "mn"
[3,] "ef" "op"
[4,] "gh" "qr"
[5,] "ij" "st"
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't used aggregate before and will look into it

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this ? If isn't, Can you be more clear? And pass the code to replicate what you are doing. But I hope this solves your problem.

```
df <- data.frame(X1 = letters[1:10], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(X1 = character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

sapply(1:round(nrow(df)/2), FUN = function(x) {
  df2[x,] <<- paste(df[(x*2-1):(x*2),], collapse = "")
})
df2
```

Comment: Yes, like that but I have many columns to apply it to. I modified your example in my question